# PHP return NULL from __construct

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to write some classes which pull my data out of my database and create objects based on that data. I'm working with CodeIgniter.

The problem is that if an `id` is supplied to the `__construct` method but no row in the database table has that `id`, an object is returned but with all the properties set to `NULL`.

Is there a way that I can check this and return `NULL` instead of an object if there is no corresponding row?

```
class JS_Model extends CI_Model
{
    protected $database_table_name;
    protected $database_keys;
    ...

    public function __construct($id = NULL){
        if($id){
            $this->getFromDatabase($id);
        }
    }

    ...

    function getFromDatabase($id){
        foreach($this->database_keys as $key){
           $this->db->select($key);
        }
        $this->db->from($this->database_table_name);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $q = $this->db->get();

        if ($q->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($q->result() as $property){     
                foreach($property as $key => $value){
                    $this->$key = $value;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // NEED TO SET THE OBJECT TO NULL FOR THIS CASE
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, once `__construct` is called, you will receive an object instance.

The correct way to handle this is to throw an `Exception` from inside the constructor.

```
class JS_Model extends CI_Model
{
    protected $database_table_name;
    protected $database_keys;

    public function __construct($id = NULL){
        if($id){
            $row = $this->getFromDatabase($id);
            if (!$row) {
                throw new Exception('requested row not found');
            }
        }
    }
}

try {
    $record = new JS_Model(1);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "record could not be found";
}
// from here on out, we can safely assume $record holds a valid record
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont you make your constructor private and use a method such as GetInstance(); something like this. Syntax may be incorrect as i dont write much php anymore :-(.

```
class JS_Model extends CI_Model
{
protected $database_table_name;
protected $database_keys;
...

private function __construct($id = NULL){

}
public static function GetInstance($id)
{
  $x = new JS_Model($id);
  $x->getFromDatabase($id);
  if(is_object($x))
  {
    return $x;
  }
  return null;

}
...

function getFromDatabase($id){
    foreach($this->database_keys as $key){
       $this->db->select($key);
    }
    $this->db->from($this->database_table_name);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($q->result() as $property){     
            foreach($property as $key => $value){
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }
    } else {
       return null;
    }
}

...

}
```